# C# Coverlet results always empty

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, coverlet

have .net core 3.1 Microsoft.net.sdk projects, with lots of async xUnit tests.

- **tried** -  adding coverlet.msbuild 2.9.0 to the project, and then running:
  `dotnet test Common\Common.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /`
  got 100% displayed, but an empty coverage file created
- **tried** - adding coverlet.collector 1.3.0 to the project and then running:
  `dotnet test Common\Common.csproj --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"`
  got a file created in testresults\{guid}\coverage.cobertura.xml - but it just says lines-covered=0

whereas stdout is saying 88 tests run in 4s.   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me coverlet.msbuild works perfect with command:
`dotnet test Common\Common.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:IncludeTestAssembly=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:ExcludeByFile=\"**/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs\"`

So, I guess you missed CoverletOutputFormat here.

Comment: thank you!   it's not the output format - but what I _was_ missing that is the key was /p:IncludeTestAssembly=true.   Now it works perfectly.

Comment: `/p:IncludeTestAssembly=true` saved my day..!!

Comment: I am using dotnet 8, from `dotnet test DemoTest\DemoTest.csproj --no-build --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --logger "trx;LogFileName=tests.xml" /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:IncludeTestAssembly=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover` - in the log all tests run, but .../TestResults/../coverage.cobertura.xml file has no sources, packages... genrated html report is empty.

Comment: @SashaBond may be try `/p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura` instead `/p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover`